# Declaring/Assigning type of ngModel in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

In my form. I have ngModel of accForm which will return object. And also there's a child rules which is an inner object. However, my class component is not accepting the declaration of model.

Basically, I want to set them into null or empty string.

This is the form:

```
<form>
  <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.index" name="index" type="hidden"/>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Admin Name</p>
    <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.name" name="name" type="text"/>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.pass" name="pass" type="password"/>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Confirm Password</p>
    <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.cpass" name="cpass" type="password"/>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Status</p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="accForm.status" name="status">
      <option>Active</option>
      <option>Inactive</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <div class="radio-group">
    <label class="radio">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.type" (change)="changeRules('superadmin')" name="type" type="radio" value="superadmin"/>
      <p>Super Admin</p>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.type" (change)="changeRules('accounting')" name="type" type="radio" value="accounting"/>
      <p>Accounting</p>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.type" (change)="changeRules('cs')" name="type" type="radio" value="cs"/>
      <p>CS</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-group">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.company" name="rules.company" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Data Company</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.member" name="rules.member" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Data Member</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.bookie" name="rules.bookie" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Data Bookie</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.bank" name="rules.bank" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Data Bank</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.journalentry" name="rules.journalentry" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Journal Entry</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.journallog" name="rules.journallog" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Journal Log</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.control" name="rules.control" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Control</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.input" name="rules.input" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Input</p>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input [(ngModel)]="accForm.rules.report" name="rules.report" type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Report</p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addsaveAccount(accForm)">Add / Save Admin Account</button>
</form>
```

What I tried so far.

```
export class ControlComponent {
    // 1st try
    accForm = any; 

    // 2nd try
    accForm = [];

    // 3rd try - still on accForm (I just tried it)
    index: any;
    name: any;
    ... and so on
    rules: any;

    // 4th try
    accForm = {
       index: null, 
       name: null,
       ... and so on,
       rules: {
          company: null,
          ... and so on
       }
    }
}
```

Error: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined // If I removed it

Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined // .. and so on

All of it doesn't work. But I also tried to remove it on accForm which becomes (index, name, pass, cpass, status, company, ... and so on)

I declared it as

```
index: number;
name: string;
pass: string;
... and so on
```

I was successful but this isn't the best way to do this. The best way is to pass the accForm object to the function when clicked | submitted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare new class.

```
export class AccForm {
  index: number;
  name: string;
  pass: string;
  rules: Rules = new Rules();
  ...
}

export class Rules {
  company: string;
  member: string;
  ...
}
```

ControlComponent:

`accForm: AccForm = new AccForm();`

Or you can use `ngForm` to submit. Read more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) and [here](http://learnangular2.com/forms/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how do I declare the inner object rules?

Comment: You need add another class for `Rules` as `AccForm`. And in `AccForm` class declare `rules: Rules = new Rules();`

Comment: Thanks alot man! It works. Kindly, edit your answer with rules. So that, the next person/programmer who needs it will identify it much easier.

Comment: You're welcome. Read more about `ngForm` for another option.